# Is there a way to bookmark or link to a section of a page without an anchor?

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, bookmarks

Is there a way to bookmark or link to an HTML page (which I am not author of) without having an anchor in the HTML code?

I want the page to get scrolled down to a particular section when accessed from a bookmark or hyperlink even if there is no anchor tag in the destination page.

Note: the destination page has an anchor tag as "foo" then bookmarking like `http:/...hello.html#foo` will not only take the user to *hello.html*, but also automatically scroll down to the section of the page so that the anchor tag "foo" is at the top of the screen.

Comment: If you would load the page in a new window. You could open it using javascript and with its reference scroll down, but you if the page changes so could the scroll count.

Comment: Thanks.Can it be done if it opens in a new tab (its ok for me even with javascript but it should not be a pop up window ).Page is quite static , will not change. Do you mean I can set a number as the length of the page to be scrolled down? I will appreciate any example .

Comment: After reviewing my original thought, if the Link is on another domain window.scrollTo will not be allowed XSS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049923/in-javascript-how-can-i-open-a-page-in-a-new-browser-window-and-scroll-to-a-spe

Answer (score 40):

It's the year 2020, there is a draft by WICG for **[Text Fragments](https://wicg.github.io/ScrollToTextFragment/#indicating-the-text-match)**, and now you can link to text on a page as if you were searching for it by adding the following to the hash

`#:~:text=<Text To Link to>`

Working example on `Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138`:

[Click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983290/is-there-a-way-to-bookmark-or-link-to-a-section-of-a-page-without-an-anchor/61703068#:~:text=Click%20on%20this%20link) Should take you to another answer page and highlight the `link there`

Comment: Unfortunately, it works more like an anchor rather than a highlighted search. It only finds and highlights the first instance. For example, [try with the word page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7983290/614277#:~:text=page), which has multiple instances here. So I could be a real munchkin right now and put the text "Click on this link" as a comment on the question and then break your example.

Comment: Also appears to be Chrome only at the moment.

Comment: Note that for this to work in a link you **must** include a `rel="noopener"` attribute in your `<a>` element, due to security restrictions.

Comment: @toraritte Thanks for the edits that you've added, but I thought the simple answer was easier to follow and showed a working example that I'd like to keep. I am trying to pick up your edits and add them as a more detailed and scientific `Read More`. You could also post it as its own answer and I could link to it :-)

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI Got it, and thanks for the heads up! I'm going to post it as an answer, but would you comment on it when you add the **Read more** more section to yours? I didn't want to post an redundant answer, but I found these tidbits, and this thread seems to be the best place to save them - so one's your answer has them too, mine will be superfluous, and will delete it. Thanks again!

Comment: Still [doesn't work in firefox and Safari](https://wpt.fyi/results/scroll-to-text-fragment/scroll-to-text-fragment.html?label=experimental&label=master&aligned)...

Answer (score 19):

You only need to have the appropriate id attribute on an element to use it like a bookmark...

```
<a href="#test">Test</a>

...

<p id="test">Hello world</p>
```

See the [W3C specification: Anchors with the `id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)

Older specifications also allowed navigation based on the `name` attribute, but this attribute has been removed from the latest HTML specifications (but if there is a `name` attribute it may be used in the same way as an `id` attribute).

If there is no `id` or `name` attribute where you wish to navigate to, there is no way of navigating to the specific point within the page, only to the page itself. In this case you may want to quote the pertinent information and supply a citation with a link or perhaps ask the author if they would add an `id`.

Comment: Should this work in any modern browser? I saw (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484719/html-anchors-with-name-or-id/484892#484892) it's not supported in NS4 (well, who cares) but how about IE6?

Comment: It works in IE6. (but you should not support anything that you are not able to test)

Comment: Are there any tricks which can link to an element that doesn't have an ID?

Comment: @Rich - many browsers also support the old `name` attribute with this too - but really you should use `id` as this is the only one the specification supports.

Comment: I'd like to link to a section in a page which isn't under my control and which has neither "id"s nor "name"s. See e.g. the various sections at http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html   I can't think of how to make that work...

Comment: @Rich - you can't in this case, you would have to link to the page and the user would have to scroll to find what they need.

Comment: I agree. Please could you add something about that to your answer? The q explicitly calls out "I am not author", but the best answer (yours) doesn't address what to do if there are neither "name" nor "id" attributes.

Comment: @Rich - I have added those details.

Comment: Likewise, id attributes are automatically DOM accessible. You don't have to set it to a variable like  `var nameElement = document.getElementById('name');`. You can just use `name` as that variable right from the start. And since you point CSS to ids with `#`, it all starts to make sense.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer is partially wrong. As the top-ranked answer by Abderrahmane TAHRI JOUTI shows, there IS a way of navigating to the specific point within the page. I came here exactly to find the "#:~:text=" attribute answer.

Answer (score 9):

<sup>This is a copy of [@AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61703068/1498178) but updated with some extra info.</sup>

It's the year 2020, and now there is a draft by WICG for **[Text Fragments](https://wicg.github.io/ScrollToTextFragment/#indicating-the-text-match)**, and now you can link to text on a page as if you were searching for it by adding the [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) quote to the URL like this:

```
#:~:text=<percent-encoded-text-quoted-from-site>
```

For example, [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210303155224/https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/#:%7E:text=%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3D%5Bprefix-) highlights the syntax from the spec.

One can also **highlight multiple sections** as well by [chaining query parameters with ampersand (`&`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#:%7E:text=multiple%20query%20parameters%20are%20separated%20by%20the%20):

```
#:~:text=<quote-1>&text=<quote-2>
```

For example, see [these highlights to the spec](https://web.archive.org/web/20210303155224/https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/#:%7E:text=Text%20Fragments%20adds%20support%20for%20specifying%20a%20text%20snippet%20in%20the%20URL%20fragment&text=the%20user%20agent%20can%20quickly%20emphasise%20).

Even **ranges** can be set in case of a longer quote (at least in Chrome):

```
#:~:text=<begin-text>,<end-text>
```

For example, [highlighting an entire paragraph in the spec](https://web.archive.org/web/20210303155224/https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/#:%7E:text=The%20core%20use%20case,the%20top%20of%20the%20page).

<sup>For some reason, in Chrome 89.0.4389.90 the above links may only work if one (1) clicks on them, (2) goes to the address bar by clicking in it or by <kbd>F6</kbd>, and (3) hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Not sure why this is when Google search constantly offers links like this in the results which work out of the box (e.g., [a link to Azure Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/basic-concepts#:%7E:text=Azure%20Key%20Vault%20is%20a,%2C%20certificates%2C%20or%20cryptographic%20keys.&text=Vaults%20support%20storing%20software%20and,keys%2C%20secrets%2C%20and%20certificates.))</sup>

#### Support

It's still spotty, but most major browsers support it (except for Firefox...). To check the current status of adoption, check out [https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A~%3A](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%7E%3A)

Comment: Thanks!  Doesn't work in Safari or Opera too. (Per CanIUse link) And Safari has a huge user footprint (18%).  Trying to make work: https://covid19criticalcare.com/covid-19-protocols/i-recover-protocol/#:~:text=<Version%201>

Comment: Clarifying:  Essentially, it only works in Chromium-based browsers.  Doesn't work in Safari or Opera (well, 1 of 3 kinds work) either. (Per CanIUse link)

Comment: Here is a code example. To link to the words "Text Fragments" on a web page, add this to the end of the URL: `#:~:text=Text%20Fragments`

Comment: Still not supported in Firefox as of September 2023.

Answer (score 2):

I must be not getting something, but sadly your solution is not working for me... The attached document's jargon confuses me a bit as the dilettant I am. :-(

Though, it gave a nice clue... Hence, I found this link with a simpler way to do this (in my case, link to a specific part of a text in some other author's blog post without ID tags):

**Share or link to quotes and text in Chrome**

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10256233?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

> *To create a link that opens directly to highlighted text:*
>
> - On your computer, open Chrome.
> - Go to a page with text that you want to share.
> - To highlight the text that you want to share, click and hold, then drag your mouse.
> - To open the context menu, right-click on the highlighted text.
> - Select Copy link to highlight.
> - If you can’t select this option, this feature may not work for the selected content.
> - Paste the link anywhere; for example, into an email or message thread.
> - Tip: To remove the highlight from the text in the linked content, right-click the highlighted text and select Remove highlight.

If you want to **link to a specific part of a PDF file online**, this solution also worked for me:

[https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html#:~:text=Open%20a%20PDF%20file%20to,end%20of%20the%20link's%20URL.](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html#:%7E:text=Open%20a%20PDF%20file%20to,end%20of%20the%20link%27s%20URL.)

Just posting this in case someone is still lost as I was.

Cheers!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32992807)

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively recent [W3C Working Group Note on Selectors and States](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/NOTE-selectors-states-20170223/) which would allow linking to selected text.

Here is a Firefox webextension partially implementing the link format (allowing you to "create" a link, based on the selection, as well as, obviously, open such a link, highlighting the correct selection):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/precise-links/

As of 2019 it seems to work fine.

Its source code is available [here](https://github.com/Treora/precise-links).

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers will try to scroll to an element with an ID that matches the hash part of the URL (i.e. if you have `<h1 id="foo">`, then `#foo` would get you there).

If everything else fails, you can use jQuery. Get the hash part from the document URL with `window.location.hash`. You can then interpret that in JavaScript to determine an element in the page.

Use `scrollTop` to move there (see [Scroll to an element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/scroll-to-an-element-with-jquery)).

See also: https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Something seems off near *"can use get the query"*. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox extension "Web Marker" does exactly what you want.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-marker/

You can find its source code and documentation here:

http://liveurls.mozdev.org/tech.html

Comment: Thanks but the web page says "Not compatible with Firefox Quantum" as of today. and also it says it was "Last updated 6 years ago (Feb 15, 2012)" :(

Answer (score 0):

If the page supports being embedded as an iframe, you can link to a document that embedds it and then autoscrolls the document. The issue is that we can't get the height of the page, so instead we just hijack the scrolling event to make the page taller once we approach the bottom:

```
data:text/html,<html><body style="margin:0; padding:0;"><iframe id='i' src='http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?CityName=Las+Vegas&state=NV&site=VEF&textField1=36.175&textField2=-115.136&e=0' width=100% frameborder=0 margin=0 scrolling=no style="height: calc(100vh + 170px + 200px);"></iframe></body><script>window.scrollTo(0, 170);window.onscroll = function(e) {if((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight - 200) {document.getElementById('i').style.height = window.innerHeight + window.scrollY + 200;}};</script></html>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, but with an extra scrollTo and timeout, I got it to work.  Too long for a comment and edit queue is full, so no editing your answer. :-(. I guess the embedded PDF made this necessary.

Comment: This is the modified bit: src='https://covid19criticalcare.com/covid-19-protocols/i-recover-protocol/' width=100% frameborder=0 margin=0 scrolling=no style="height: calc(100vh + 170px + 200px);"></iframe></body><script>window.scrollTo(0, 1000); setTimeout(() => {  window.scrollTo(0, 1200); }, 3000);  window.onscroll

Answer (score -2):

The *AnchorMe* addon from Firefox just solved this for me. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + double click on your desired destination and voilà.