# link to location on page without id or name

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I'm looking to link to a page on a 3rd party site with a heavy amount of content, but want the reader to head half way down and read from there.  Yes, I could specifically tell them to, but sometimes it's not always ideal.  If I can't find any element with a name or id attribute in the general location, is there any other method?  Thanks!

Comment: quite confusing. what do you really want?

Comment: He wants to scrol page on other site, he goes by link, to sertain point, but when page have no # which can be used as part of link. It's interesting task, but not sure if any adequate solutions possible

Comment: It looks like there's a way for IE only, using Javascript. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp ("top" under "specs")

Comment: Something like a universal URI that work even without a name or id attribute, but for instance based on XPath, would be great !

Comment: If the 3rd party site is in an `<iframe>` you could search the content for an element containing a string of text with jQuery (or others) `$(':contains('the text')')` and than use `.scrollTop()`..

Comment: A duplicate of [Is there any way to bookmark or link to a section of a page without an anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983290/is-there-any-way-to-bookmark-or-link-to-a-section-of-a-page-without-an-anchor/), and the answer in 2020 is **yes** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61703068/1498178)), via W3C [Text Fragments](https://wicg.github.io/ScrollToTextFragment/#indicating-the-text-match).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to bookmark or link to a section of a page without an anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983290/is-there-any-way-to-bookmark-or-link-to-a-section-of-a-page-without-an-anchor)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if the user is using Google Chrome. To generate the link, go to the website in chrome, highlight the text, right click and click "Copy link to highlight." Keep in mind that the text will be highlighted when they link to it. This is the syntax of the link:

`https://stackoverflow.com/#:~:text=Looking%20for%20more`

Here's the actual example of the above as a demonstration: [https://stackoverflow.com/#:~:text=Looking%20for%20more](https://stackoverflow.com/#:%7E:text=Looking%20for%20more)

The last time I checked in Jan 2023 it didn't work in Firefox, but things are always changing.