# Apply style only to anchors defining links

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, anchor

I have this

```
<a href="http://www.lipsum.com/" target="_blank"> LIPSUM </a>
<h1> <a href="#first"> Chapter 1 </a> </h1>
<h1> <a href="#second"> Chapter 2 </a> </h1>
<h2> <a name="first"> First part</a> </h2>
<h2> <a name="second"> A second part </a> </h2>
```

plus this

```
a:hover {color: orange}
```

How can I set it so that the `<h2>` tags (last 2) won't change color when I hover over them? Because I still need the anchor tags there.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, it's not homework. I followed a tutorial and was wondering if this was possible and I couldn't find any solution by searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be excluding `<h2>` *parent* elements by [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class:

```css
:not(h2) > a:hover { color: orange; }
```

```html
<a href="http://www.lipsum.com/" target="_blank"> LIPSUM </a>
<h1> <a href="#first"> Chapter 1 </a> </h1>
<h1> <a href="#second"> Chapter 2 </a> </h1>
<h2> <a name="first"> First part</a> </h2>
<h2> <a name="second"> A second part </a> </h2>
```

Where `>` is the direct descendant (child) combinator.

> **[8.2. Child combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)**
>
> A child combinator describes a childhood relationship between two
>   elements. A child combinator is made of the "greater-than sign"
>   (U+003E, >) character and separates two sequences of simple selectors.

It's worth noting that [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class [is supported in IE 9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) and newer.

---

### Avoid `name` attribute on `<a>`

You should note that `name` attribute [is **obsolete**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-a-name) in HTML5. You could instead use `id` to an element in order to [make it a bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983290/is-there-any-way-to-bookmark-or-link-to-a-section-of-a-page-without-an-anchor).

Hence you can get rid of redundant `<a>` elements which caused the trouble.

```css
a:hover { color: orange; }
```

```html
<a href="http://www.lipsum.com/" target="_blank"> LIPSUM </a>
<h1> <a href="#first"> Chapter 1 </a> </h1>
<h1> <a href="#second"> Chapter 2 </a> </h1>
<h2 id="first">First part</h2>
<h2 id="second">A second part</h2>
```

---

Alternatively, If by any reason you would like to stick with the current markup, for legacy web browsers such as IE 8 and older, you could **either** override the declaration:

```
h2 > a:hover { color: blue; }
```

**Or** target only `<a>` elements having an `href`; I.e. only select links.

```css
a[href]:hover { color: orange; }
```

```html
<a href="http://www.lipsum.com/" target="_blank"> LIPSUM </a>
<h1> <a href="#first"> Chapter 1 </a> </h1>
<h1> <a href="#second"> Chapter 2 </a> </h1>
<h2> <a name="first"> First part</a> </h2>
<h2> <a name="second"> A second part </a> </h2>
```

Comment: :not(h2) a:hover { color: orange; } doesn't work for me, although the second solution does. Thanks!

Comment: @Florin I updated the answer, you should use child combinator instead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, by your HTML provided, you could follow a lot of patterns here. Depends on your scenario.

**Apply only to anchors descendand of `h1`:**

```
h1 a:hover {color: orange; }
```

**Apply only to anchors that doesn't descendand from `h2`:**

```
:not(h2) a:hover {color: orange; }
```

**Apply only to anchors that are descendant of the first 2 `h`'s, not the last 2**

```
:nth-child(4n+2) a:hover {color: orange; }
```

**Apply only to anchors that have a `name`, instead of a `href`**

```
a[name]:hover {color: orange; }
```

The possibilities are endless.

Comment: Sweet! And applying to anchors that have href? That would ease it up :)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply h2's color as important.
For ex. h2{color: #000 !important}

Comment: There's still color changing on hovering over h2 tags with this solution.